# problem with using getElementById().getValue in FBJS/Facebook !

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, fbjs

I am using this code to generate hidden HTML code in Facebook :

```
echo "<div id=\"y257y\" style=\"display:none;\">".$fdesc."</div>";
```

And, I am trying to get this element back in JS using the following code

```
newVal=document.getElementById('y257y').getValue();
```

But, I am getting an error: Undefined

Can anyone kindly help me out ?

Thanks.

-
ahsan

Comment: Just a quick recommendation: `echo "<div id='y257y' style='display:none;'>".$fdesc."</div>";`

Comment: Even better: `<div id="y257y" style="display:none;"><?php echo $fdesc; ?></div>` | What makes you think the exists the function `getValue()` ?

Comment: @Felix Kling: I am working wth FBJS and theres a function getValue() as mentioend here : http://developers.facebook.com/docs/fbjs/

Comment: @Ahsan: I see. But this table shows a translation of JavaScript attributes to FBJS methods. The attribute `value` translates to `getValue()` and only *form* elements have this attribute. It was never possible to get the content of an arbitrary element with `value`. From what I read on this page, it seems you just can't access the the HTML. I hope you also read the note at the top. It seems the don't recommend to use FBML anymore.

Comment: Hidden HTML in Facebook, eh? Sounds ominous.

Comment: Don't Facebook add numbers to the IDs when using FBJS? so your id will look like `XXXXXXXXXX_y257y` ?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of:

```
newVal = document.getElementById('y257y').getValue();
```

try using:

```
newVal = document.getElementById('y257y').innerHTML;
```

Are you using any JavaScript library, like jQuery or Prototype? If you're using jQuery:

```
newVal = $('#y257y').html();
```

#### Other suggestions:

Use hidden form element:

```
echo "<input type=hidden id=y257y value=\"$fdesc\">";
```

and in JavaScript:

```
newVal = document.getElementById('y257y').value;
```

Or just output a `<script>` tag:

```
echo "<script>newVal = \"$fdesc\";</script>";
```

and there's no need to find the value in the DOM – it's already in JavaScript.

Comment: I am trying to work with FBJS. The restrictions here are ...you can not  "get" using innerHTML. you can only "set". thanks for trying to help me out, but is there any other suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a textarea? Since at least that may have a getValue method if you are really lucky:

```
$fdesc = str_replace('<', '&lt;', $fdesc);
$fdesc = str_replace('>', '&gt;', $fdesc);

echo "<textarea id=\"y257y\" style=\"display:none;\">".$fdesc."</textarea>";
newVal=document.getElementById('y257y').getValue();
newVal = newVal.replace("&gt;", ">")
newVal = newVal.replace("&lt;", "<")
```

But something tells me that is not going to work for you, facebook may not like it.
Seems easier just to do this:

```
$fdesc = <<<EOD
 <div>Here is your html</div>
 <p>And some more </p>
EOD;

$fdesc = str_replace("'", "\'", $fdesc);   //Escape single quotes
$fdesc = str_replace("\n", "";', $fdesc);   //Get rid of line breaks

 echo "var fdesc = '$fdesk';";
```